# SwiftUI: Can you use AppStorage with decoded json?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a list of countries and a field on them is `favorite`.  If a user toggles the favorite button, that country's bool value of `favorite` is `true`.  Elsewhere in my code, I use `favorites` to filter through all the countries and have a separate view that just shows the favorite countries.

```
@State var countries: [Country] = Bundle.main.decode("Countries.json")

var favorites : [Country] {
    return countries.filter { $0.favorite }
}
```

I want to persist the `countries` so that I can reload the favorites view on subsequent app visits.  Can I use `@AppStorage` for this or am I going about this the wrong way?  CoredData seemed a bit like overkill when I was looking into it.  I am new to SwiftUI coming to Javascript so apologies if this seems trivial.

Comment: Saving the favorite flag using @AppStorage is a good idea but not the whole list of countries, this can be stored in a file instead

Answer (score 0):

In your case optimal will be to use [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/)

Use this part of code in `func()` or `init()`

For saving data in `UserDefaults`:

```
    if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode([Country]) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Countries")
    }
```

For loading data from `UserDefaults`:

```
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Countries") {
        if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Country], from: data) {  }
    }
```

p/s
And I would like to recommend [SwiftUI Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) from Apple if you are beginner